# How to make Angularjs $http.delete and asp.net mvc4 minification work together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I'm working on an AngularJs/asp.net mvc4 app that communicates with the backend through asp.net mvc web api.

The minification of javascript files is done with mvc4, but when i use `$http.delete` in angular code, the mvc4 minifyer return following error in the bundled file:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1029,11-17): run-time warning JS1010: Expected identifier: delete
(1029,11-17): run-time error JS1137: 'delete' is a new reserved word and should not be used as an identifier: delete
```

I have done a workaround that replaces reserved words (in this case 'delete'), which is described here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418911/1029874

This means that `$http.delete` will be replaced with `$http.fooDelete`, resulting that angular do not recognize it any more.

Is there another workaround or is the simplest solution to use jQuery ajax instead?

Comment: Use `$http['delete']()` and try not to use jQuery ajax ever while in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

@larchii use $http'delete' as @stewie mentioned. As per [this article](http://tech.pro/blog/1238/angularjs-and-ie8-gotcha-http-delete), use of any of the IE reserved words causes the expected identifier error to be thrown. There is also a link to the list of reserved words for IE. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but my workaround will be to do this instead of using the shortcuts:

```
$http({method: 'DELETE', url: '/someUrl'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```