# Angular services/resources handling

Tags: angularjs

Basically I am a little bit unsure how should I create/manage my resource. I am thinking about resource as a model like in (MVC) background. So for example this is my factory:

```
angular.module('resources.question', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Question', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/:questionId', {questionId: '@id'}, {
            postTest: {method: 'POST', url: '/create/:pageId/:questionId', params: {questionId: 0}},
            search: {method: 'GET', url: '/search/:query', params: {query: ''}, isArray: true},
            edit: {method: 'GET', url: '/edit/:pageQuestionId'},
            delete: {method: 'GET', url: '/delete/:pageQuestionId'},
            addExisting: {method: 'GET', url: '/addtopage/:pageId/:questionId'}
        });
    });
```

I am noticing that I have some repeating tasks, like inserting data. For example:

```
var newQuestion = Question.addExisting({
    pageId: data.pageId,
    questionId: data.questionId,
    id: $scope.data.search.question.id
});
//update object from database
$rootScope.survey.pages[data.pageIndex].questions.splice(data.questionIndex, 0, newQuestion); //insert the data
```

So basically I am not sure how to handle similar situations. Does my factory needs to extended somehow to handle this kind of data manipulation, or do I need to create another factory for these kind of tasks. Or it's just me over-thinking this ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just abstract away all the repeated code into another service and inject that into your controller or wherever you are using the current resource?

Setup something like a questionManagement service where you inject your current question service and create an API where you work on the question domain at a higher level. Put all the  things that you do after a response to the resource comes back in those various methods.

Remember since all this will be async that you will either need to implement promises via the $q service or a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but be careful with your custom $resource action names. Using `delete` could [cause problems if you try to *minify* your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413844/mvc4-bundle-minification-doesnt-work-with-javascript-reserved-words), as it is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in Javascript. Its generally considered bad practice to use [reserved words](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) as property names.

with insight from here:

- [Browser support for using a reserved word as a property name in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306315/browser-support-for-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-property-name-in-javascript)
- [using reserved words as property names, revisited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022397/using-reserved-words-as-property-names-revisited)
- [Is it safe to declare a delete method in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793529/is-it-safe-to-declare-a-delete-method-in-javascript?lq=1)